# Has it become too hard to write self-answered questions?

Tags: discussion, soft-question, self-answer

Recently I posted a [self-answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858862/can-we-name-every-object-in-every-model-of-every-first-order-theory) which I had been working on in the [Sandbox for drafts of long, complex posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts/11872#11872) for $2$ months (August $10^{th}$ to October $10^{th}$), which underwent $44$ revisions before it was posted. I also vetted the answer in the [logic room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55200761#55200761) to make sure it was correct before posting.

Despite the effort involved the question still got closed, although I was able to get the question reopened by addressing the critical feedback in the comments. After it was reopened, $4$ downvotes were received between the question & answer within a short timeframe.

The  process of learning new content to edit the question, asking for it to be reopened, and now this meta post has taken a lot of time. I also went to [constructive feedback](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback) to ask for possible explanations regarding the downvotes, since no comments were left.

Should self answer questions really require this much involvement? I learnt a lot from writing this question and from the feedback I got, but the closure and downvotes were rather unwelcome and time consuming.

Comment: The question is not closed. Two downvotes only for the question I see.

Comment: @Aryadeva In the $3^{rd}$ paragraph, I mentioned that the question was reopened. You were right about the downvotes on the question, I have changed it to refer to downvotes shared between the question and answer.

Comment: I see no evidence that your post is received negatively because it is self-answered.

Comment: @ArcticChar Can you think of any other reason why the question and answer were downvoted? Both votes appeared after the comments were addressed and it was reopened.

Comment: People downvote for all kinds of crazy reasons, or for no reason at all. If the downvoter doesn't give a reason, then we are reduced to pure speculation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fact that your question was written to be answered by yourself is a red herring here, and has nothing to do with the reception of your question.  The first thing you should be asking yourself is "Is my question a good question, per the [site guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)?"  My first impression of the linked question—even in the current state—is that it doesn't really meet those standards.  The original version of the question (barring the meta-commentary about the question being a self-answered question) reads:

> Is it possible to name every object in every model of any first order theory? I would like this question to be answered using Tarskian semantics, where names refer to objects external to the logic.

What is actually *required* by way of context is likely somewhat opinion-based, but, at the very least, you should have defined what you meant by a "name" from the start.  Personally, I would also appreciate a short précis describing Tarskian semantics (or, at least, a link to such), though I recognize that the target audience of this question probably already knows what the phrase means.  Finally, I would like to see some indication as to why anyone should *care*.  Why should we care whether or not every object can be named?  What is the significance of *Tarskian* semantics in this question, rather than some other system?

So, again:  my guess is that the poor reception of your question has nothing to do with the fact that it is self-answered, and everything to do with the fact that readers just don't think that the question is terribly interesting, well-motivated, or context-ified.

Comment: This explains why the question was received poorly, but not the answer. That said I have taken your suggestions and edited the question to give a justification for using Tarskain semantics, linked to its definition, and given some brief motivation for the question. Please let me know if you think that this is (in)sufficient.

Answer (score -6):

Had the same problem before as well and I too made a similar meta post [over here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32467/is-self-answering-own-questions-a-frowned-upon-practice-in-math-stack-exchange). What I understood is that most of the stack exchange wants the site to become a 'give help-get help' site with its reputation system rather than be a site which is a knowledge repository/ a treasury of mathematical ideas.

This is not a bad thing, you just have to use it the way the community wants it to be. As per the amount of hard work that you've put into the answer, I suggest you either write a personal blog post elsewhere or maybe publish your result in a paper if you are in the position too and the idea is big enough.

Hope this helps.

P.s: I do not intend to offend anyone here but this was my personal experience.

**for OP:** do not take this incident personally. There is a lot of other help/ use you can make of this site.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the most important conclusion to make here. Both of these meta questions have relatively highly-voted (and in your case, even accepted) answers which make the case that the self-answered questions being referred to aren't very good questions. Contrast with something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3681799/2-out-of-3-property-for-faithfully-flat-ring-maps) which is a self-answered question which does a much better job of fulfilling community standards about what a good question is and has been voted accordingly.